# Pug template: multiline class literal

Tags: pug

It is posible to write this [class literal](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#class-literal) concatenation?:

```
p.class1.class2.class3.class4.class5...class10
```

into multiple lines, something like this?:

```
p.class1.class2.class3 |
 .class4.class5...class10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you need to write your classes over multiple lines, you'll need to use the [standard attribute syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#multiline-attributes):

```
p(class='
  class1
  class2
  class3
')
```

Comment: I have to use `\`` instead of `'`.